# Empty all fields except one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clear all text except one field using js

Used below code :

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('.isMobile').length < 0) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

`$(this).hasClass('.isMobile').length` used this to check particular field has some class.

But `$(this).hasClass('.isMobile').length` showing undefined every time.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop for that, you only need to narrow down your jQuery selector :

```
$('input[type=text].isMobile').val('');
```

If you want to exclude the input with the class `isMobile` instead :

```
$('input[type=text]:not(.isMobile)').val('');
```